# Tag NAV não ocupa a largura especificada

Tags: html5, css3

A tag `NAV` não ocupa a largura de 1200px especificada, ficando menor do que o requerido. E a tag `NAV` do próximo menu ocupa a linha não ocupada pela `NAV` superior.

Veja o exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como falado a tag `NAV` de cor laranja não ocupa os 1200px de largura, com isso a tag `NAV` abaixo sobe para ocupar o que não foi preenchido pela `NAV` superior.

**CSS NAV cor laranja:**

```
/* Menu principal */

nav.menuprincipal{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
nav.menuprincipal a{
  color:#ffffff;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF8922;
}
nav.menuprincipal ul{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
nav.menuprincipal ul li{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
nav.menuprincipal a:hover{
  background-color: #DD6900;
}
```

**Tag NAV inferior:**

```
.menudestaques{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.menudestaques a{
  color:#222;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.menudestaques ul{
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
.menudestaques ul li{
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="menuprincipal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Notícias">NOTÍCIAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Imóveis">IMÓVEIS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Colunistas">COLUNISTAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Guarapari">GUARAPARI</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Cidades Vizinhas">CIDADES VIZINHAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Praias">PRAIAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Empregos">EMPREGOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Cuinária">CULINÁRIA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Guia Comercial">GUIA COMERCIAL</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="menudestaques">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Praias de Guarapari">Praias</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Turismo Rural">Turismo Rural</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Horários de Ônibus">Horários de Ônibus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Telefones Úteis">Telefones Úteis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Onde Hospedar">Onde Hospedar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Onde Comer">Onde Comer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Parques Ecológicos">Parques Ecológicos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Imóveis">Imóveis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Taxi">Taxi</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: O problema está na imagem que está em sidebar. Pode postar o código também? Executando o código que você postou não gera nenhum problema.

Comment: @Everson Gera o problema sim amigo, fiz a execução conforme você falou e dá o mesmo problema. Pois a o menu laranja não ocupa os 1200px, pode perceber que o menu inferior ocupa o espaço deixado pelo menu superior.

Comment: Então seu monitor tem menos que 1200px. Meu monitor é maior que essa resolução e não da problema. Mas como [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214289/57801), max-width defini o tamanho máximo que irá ocupar. E não o tamanho em si. Vou ver uma solução e te informo.

Comment: adicione `overflow: auto` dentro de `nav.menuprincipal` que irá funcionar. Isso fará que respeite o tamanho da linha.

Comment: @Everson Solucionou a questão do menu inferior não ocupar o espaço do menu laranja. Mas o menu laranja continua com 1130px e não com 1200px.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Max-width é a largura máxima que o elemento pode ocupar.
> ```

Não que ele vá ocupar de fato ... Mas como está 'setado' para  `width;100%` eu creio que seu elemento pai esteja restringindo a largura dele. Veja no devTools se é isto.

Ou poste o código dele também, se já estiver hospedado, o site se possível.

Comment: Infelizmente não é.